# What is wrong with this "for dummies" PHP code?

Tags: php

I am running PHP5 on a free web server and I am trying to learn PHP reading a "for dummies" book...It gives me some code to run and for some infuriating reason I get errors on every line that echos HTML.

here is the code. specifics have been Xed out but they are accurate:

```
<?php
/* Program: mysql_up.php
* Desc: Connects to MySQL Server and
* outputs settings.
*/
echo “<html>
<head><title>Test MySQL</title></head>
<body>”;
$host=”XXXX”;
$user=”XXXX”;
$password=”XXXX”;
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
$sql=”SHOW STATUS”;
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
if($result == false)
{
echo “<h4>Error: “.mysqli_error($cxn).”</h4>”;
}
else
{
/* Table that displays the results */
echo “<table border=’1’>
<tr><th>Variable_name</th>
<th>Value</th></tr>”;
for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
echo “<tr>”;
$row_array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
for($j = 0;$j < mysqli_num_fields($result);$j++)
{
echo “<td>”.$row_array[$j].”</td>\n”;
}
}
echo “</table>”;
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Whenever it gets to a line that echos HTML I get this error or similar:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in /home/a7613610/public_html/mysql_up.php on line 6

I want to learn PHP but when it reports errors in supposedly good code it makes me not want to.

Comment: You should be using " instead of “ for quotes and the same thing for ’, it should be '

Comment: try single quotes instead??? looks like you are using the wierd double quotes, what did you write this in? word?

Comment: When you're learning a language and the compiler tells you there is a problem....then you have a problem and not good code.

Comment: I challenge ANYONE to find the difference between those two quotes on the first comment line ;)

Comment: copy/pasted it from a "for dummies" book

Comment: If you want to learn PHP you'll have to get used to writing it by hand...

Comment: @BoltClock - sed 's/PHP/any programming language/'

Comment: I am using notepad by the way. Copy/pasted the code from there.

Comment: Notepad can still handle curly quotes, which it appears you have in your code. Change them to standard quotes (delete the quote, and manually type a new one). Then shoot the people who put the code samples together.

Comment: while notepad is pretty good (i've developed some pretty neat apps in notepad) you might want to consider notepad++ or after a while even an IDE (ie. netbeans). It helps you a lot, not in the last place by offering syntax highlighting (which visually separates different kinds of statements), by means of which you can easily spot errors in your code!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is riddled with fancy quotes  (`“` and `”`) which PHP cannot cope with. You could use your text editor to do a find and replace for both characters with the generic double quote character `"`. <del>Although it definitely looks like you're **not** using a plain text editor (see [Mike Caron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408379/what-is-wrong-with-this-for-dummies-php-code/3408411#3408411)), I hope you're using one. Word-processing and rich text editing software is not designed for writing programs and scripts.</del>

OK, so you're using Notepad to write your PHP code. That's great, but be aware that some eBook readers and even some books themselves mess with quote characters in code blocks and turn them fancy. This is one reason why copying and pasting code is frowned on ;)

Also, if you want to learn PHP, or any form of programming in general, you should probably not expect books and tutorials to be perfect ;)

Comment: @JBlue: it's OK though, as long as you're *learning*. This fancy quote issue is also pretty obscure at first to beginners. I once read the same book that your code comes from and I must say it's a pretty decent read.

Comment: also, there's a difference between double and single quotes " and ' in php.  stuff in single quotes is skipped over while stuff in double quotes is processed.  so echo "$stuff" will echo the contents of $stuff, while echo '$stuff' will echo exactly $stuff.

Answer (score 6):

NEVER USE MICROSOFT WORD FOR DEVELOPMENT OF ANY KIND!

I apologize for shouting, but this is really important. Use notepad, or use any other text editor. But, never, ever use Word or any word processor for coding!

Comment: but, I used wordstar 25+ years ago when I started programming (it had a 7 bit mode that occasionally failed, so we wrote another program that read our source code, turning the 8th bit off)

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are wrong. Use the normal quotes like " and not the ones you copied (“)!

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered, but since you're a rookie in PHP (and apparently in programming), I would like to add, regarding Mike Caron's answer, that you should avoid coding in windows notepad.

I once had a MAJOR white-space problem, because I edited a PHP file in windows notepad (It took me about 2 hours to figure it out).

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download), is a must for starters.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what others have pointed out, these lines

```
echo “<table border=’1’>
<tr><th>Variable_name</th>
<th>Value</th></tr>”;
```

Should be just one line

```
echo "<table border=’1’><tr><th>Variable_name</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
```

Marcelo.

Comment: The newlines will be printed out as is. I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: BoltClock, OMG! I just made a test and you're absolutely right! It is my editor, (EditPlus 2.12), that seems to have the wrong syntax file and marks it as invalid.... Oh, well, something new everyday :-) Cheers,  Marcelo.